# Best way to set up and record DVB-C PAL and share recorded streams with DNLA on Ubuntu?

Tags: server

I have an EyeTV Hybrid DVB-C USB (plus a few Pinnacle DVB-T ones) receiver which works well under OS X, but I would like to have recording under Ubuntu instead - preferrably with EPG -and share with DNLA to my tv set.

What would be the best way to do so in terms of programs etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MythTV. Big and bulky but it [supports most hardware](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Category%3aVideo_capture_cards) and has a [built-in UPnP server](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/UPnP).

Comment: With that you may want to go with Mythbuntu [http://www.mythbuntu.org] which has MythTV heavily integrated into the Ubuntu Desktop environment.